# In simple form get the error_notification text without generating a validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In my simple_forms form, I have `<%= f.error_notification %>` which shows the alert box at the top of the form when there is a validation issue.

By default - this error notification seems to show :

```
Please review the problems below:
```

I want to show this error notification sometimes before the form is submitted (I use javascript validation too). How can I get the error_notification value, without having triggered a POST to the backend controller?

I know I could obviously create this error notification div myself, but if I can reuse the simple_form one, and I change the error_notification message itd be nice to have that carry through.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please rephrase the question?

From what you said above, you want to show the errors, any errors before the post, right? But rails do it for you. It adds this code snippet at the beginning of your partial _form.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Here my 'user' is the name I used on generate.